# File upload not working in PHP , $_POST['file'] , not able to extract file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form action="mail/filesend.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" validate>
    <div class="input-wrpr">
        <input type="file" name="files[]">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">
        Send File
    </button>       
</form>
```

And then the following file upload code in jQuery:

```
$(function () {


    let files = null;

    $('input[type="file"]').on('change' , (e) => {
        files = e.target.files;
    });


    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

            let data = new FormData();
            // files = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;   

            $.each(files, function(key, value){
                data.append(key, value);
            });

            console.log(data.getAll('0'));
            // console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url : $(this).attr('action'),
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false, // Don't process the files
                contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                data : data
            }).done(function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                if (! data.success) {
                    // console.log(data.errors);
                    /*for(let er in data.errors) {
                        console.log(data.errors[er])
                    }*/
                    console.log(data);
                } else {
                    /* else condition fires if form submission is successful ! */
                    console.log(data.file); 
                }
            }).fail(function(data){
                console.log(data);  
            });

    });



});
```

And the following PHP code for testing :

```
<?php  

// You need to add server side validation and better error handling here

$data = array();

if(isset($_FILES['files'])) {  

    $data = array('file' => 'I a in if');
}
else {
    $data = array('file' => 'I am in else');
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Now when i check my console i see that the PHP if condition is not passing , that is it is unable to detect:

```
isset($_POST['files'])
```

Why is this happening ? I have tried using `isset($_FILES['files'])`, also I have tried renaming my html file input field to just `files` instead of `files[]` , but this does't seem to work , What am I doing wrong ?

I was following the tutorial **[HERE](https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)**. But somehow the example I have created just does't work.

Comment: What an error you are getting?

Comment: `isset($_POST['files'])` alone will not do anything, debug it properly using var_dump()

Comment: check the `isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])` in mail/filesend.php

Comment: add `$(this)[0]` inside `let data = new FormData();` and it should look like `let data = new FormData($(this)[0]);`. Remove  `$.each(files,function(key, value){data.append(key, value);});` this code from ajax

Comment: @PankajMakwana sure will try that , ggupta , will try that TY !

Answer (score 0):

Try to `print_r($_FILES)` and check if it shows an array of file,
If it does, use the same key in `$_FILES['same_key_here']` and it supposed to work,
Let me know if it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send files, do something like this.
This may help you.

```
var fileInput = $("#upload_img")[0]; // id of your file
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image_file",fileInput.files[0]);  //'xmlfile' will be your key
```

Check in your php code like,

```
echo $_POST['image_file'];
```